# Initial call with a JAX-WS web service client - cost and how it can be enhanced

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP Hello World web service built using Metro 2.2. I have a matching WS client. I have a local copy of the WSDL clientside.

My first call is always systematically much more expensive (up to 10x) than the subsequent calls. What causes that? How can I get around it? How can I measure the source of the latency?

Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing code, it's hard to answer, but assuming you're using JAX-WS to call the service:  1. Initial loading of service-specific classes. 2. You could try creating the service and obtaining a port on startup to pre-load the classes, but really, it shouldn't matter, since it only happens once.  3. Try [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jvisualvm.html).

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know exactly what's wrong but in some projects I experienced the same behaviour and did some tests and I could gain a lot)

First I thought that the WSDL or the generated classes (usually caused by the bad WSDL) are the problem. But if you are just the client, then you can't change this anyway.

The biggest differences in start up (1-2 min down to 1-2 s for big WSDLs, and also more performance in general) I experienced when I didn't create a jar file for the client, I just created a .bat and .sh to still be able to start the client comfortably (I tried all different jar options, package libraries into the jar is obviously the worst). Some web service clients with huge WSDL files couldn't be executed at all otherwise (and generating the classes also only worked with CXF and not with Axis).

You might also gain something by extracting the libraries. I guess those huge differences have something to do with unpacking the required classes from the numerous required libraries, but to be honest: I don't know, but it helped in my cases.